# Trust certificate for OCSP, but not for client certs?

Tags: nginx, configuration, ssl-certificate, x509, ocsp

According to the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html), you can specify certificates to be trusted for *both* OCSP response and client certificate verification:

> **ssl_trusted_certificate** / **ssl_client_certificate**
>
> Specifies a file with trusted CA certificates in the PEM format used to verify client certificates and OCSP responses if ssl_stapling is enabled.

**Is there a way to trust a certificate *only* for OCSP signing, but not for client certificates?**